# How to use Cordova plugins with Expo?

Tags: react-native, cordova, cordova-plugins, expo

I have created a react-native project with expo. Now I was wondering if there is a way to use Cordova plugins for this like creating a bridge or something between both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but in . expo you cant. Expo doesnt give any hold on native modules, becuase of its wrapper ,i.e ExpoKit. Even you cant download any external libraries that requires native linking in expo. If you want to approach that way, then you have to eject from expo to pure react native. And there you can link your own native modules.

Do check this out , might help you [nativen moudles RN](https://medium.com/wix-engineering/creating-a-native-module-in-react-native-93bab0123e46)